# Iphone 5 - 6plus image size/resolutions?

Tags: ios, image, resolution, iphone-5, iphone-6-plus

I'm working on the graphics for an app that will run in portrait mode only for the iPhone 5 - 6 plus. The images should be the total width of the portrait screen. Based on this page:
    http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions it looks as if my image widths should be as follows:

```
x = 640 pixels in width, 
2x = 750 pixels in width, 
3x = 1125 pixels in width
```

Does the above look correct?

When creating these images in Photoshop is it best to save them at 72 ppi?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your refer to them as "x", "2x" and "3x", but the screen widths (native for iPhone 4/5/6, virtual for 6 Plus) are:

- 640 pixels (iPhone 4/5)
- 750 pixels (iPhone 6)
- 1242 pixels (iPhone 6 Plus)

The ppi resolution doesn't matter if you set the sizes in pixels. It only matters if you set the size in cm, inches or similar length units. If you want to see them at their "real" size, you should select 326 ppi for iPhone 4/5/6 and 461 ppi for 6 Plus.

Comment: I always use this page when I have some doubts about screen resolutions : http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions